# Escaping commas in macro output

Tags: macros, rust

I am trying to write a macro which enables me to transform
`(a, b, c, d)` to `(a, a + b, a + b + c, a + b + c + d)`, etc. Here is what I have got so far:

```
macro_rules! pascal_next {
    ($x: expr) => ($x);
    ($x: expr, $y: expr) => (
        ($x, $x + $y)
    );
    ($x: expr, $y: expr, $($rest: expr),+) => (
        ($x, pascal_next!(
                $x + $y, $($rest),+
            )
        )
    );
}
```

However, there is a problem that it would actually output (a, (a + b, (a + b + c, a + b + c +d))). The origin is that the second matching rule `($x: expr, $y: expr) => (($x, $x + $y));`, produces an extra bracket, so that there would be nested brackets. If I don't put a bracket outside, I would get the error error:

> unexpected token: `,`

So is it possible to output a comma `,` in Rust macros?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No; the result of a macro **must** be a complete grammar construct like an expression or an item.  You **absolutely cannot** have random bits of syntax like a comma or a closing brace.

You can get around this by simply not outputting anything until you have a complete, final expression.  Behold!

````rust
#![feature(trace_macros)]

macro_rules! pascal_impl {
    /*
    The input to this macro takes the following form:

    ```ignore
    (
        // The current output accumulator.
        ($($out:tt)*);

        // The current additive prefix.
        $prefix:expr;

        // The remaining, comma-terminated elements.
        ...
    )
    ```
    */

    /*
    Termination condition: there is no input left.  As
    such, dump the output.
    */
    (
        $out:expr;
        $_prefix:expr;
    ) => {
        $out
    };

    /*
    Otherwise, we have more to scrape!
    */
    (
        ($($out:tt)*);
        $prefix:expr;
        $e:expr, $($rest:tt)*
    ) => {
        pascal_impl!(
            ($($out)* $prefix+$e,);
            $prefix+$e;
            $($rest)*
        )
    };
}

macro_rules! pascal {
    ($($es:expr),+) => { pascal_impl!((); 0; $($es),+,) };
}

trace_macros!(true);

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", pascal!(1, 2, 3, 4));
}
````

**Note**: To use this on a stable compiler, you will need to delete the `#![feature(trace_macros)]` and `trace_macros!(true);` lines.  Everything else should be fine.

What this does is it recursively munches away at the input, passing the partial (and potentially *semantically invalid*) output as *input* to the next level of recursion.  This lets us build up an "open list", which we couldn't otherwise do.

Then, once we're out of input, we just re-interpret our partial output as a complete expression and... done.

The reason I including the tracing stuff is so I could show you what it looks like as it runs:

```
pascal! { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 }
pascal_impl! { (  ) ; 0 ; 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , }
pascal_impl! { ( 0 + 1 , ) ; 0 + 1 ; 2 , 3 , 4 , }
pascal_impl! { ( 0 + 1 , 0 + 1 + 2 , ) ; 0 + 1 + 2 ; 3 , 4 , }
pascal_impl! { ( 0 + 1 , 0 + 1 + 2 , 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 , ) ; 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 ; 4 , }
pascal_impl! { ( 0 + 1 , 0 + 1 + 2 , 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 , 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 , ) ; 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ; }
```

And the output is:

```
(1, 3, 6, 10)
```

One thing to be aware of: large numbers of un-annotated integer literals can cause a *dramatic* increase in compile times.  If this happens, you can solve it by simply annotating *all* of your integer literals (like `1i32`).