# Can macros expand array/vector into multiple indexed arguments?

Tags: macros, rust

Is it possible to write a macro that expands an expression into multiple indexed arguments, which can be passed to a function or another macro?

See this simple self contained example.
The aim is to have `unpack3` expand `v` into `v[0], v[1], v[2]`.

```
macro_rules! elem {
    ($val:expr, $($var:expr), *) => {
        $($val == $var) || *
    }
}

// attempt to expand an array.
macro_rules! unpack3 {
    ($v:expr) => {
        $v[0], $v[1], $v[2]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 2;
    let vars = [0, 1, 3];
    // works!
    if elem!(a, vars[0], vars[1], vars[2]) {
        println!("Found!");
    }
    // fails!
    if elem!(a, unpack3!(vars)) {
        println!("Found!");
    }
}
```

The second example fails, is it possible to make this work?

Possible solutions could include:

- Changing use of macro grammar.
- Using tuples, then expanding into arguments after.
- Re-arranging the expressions to workaround macro constraints.

---

Note, this may be related to [Escaping commas in macro output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195529/escaping-commas-in-macro-output) but don't think its a duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

This is impossible in two different ways.

First, to quote the answer to the question you yourself linked: "No; the result of a macro **must** be a complete grammar construct like an expression or an item. You **absolutely cannot** have random bits of syntax like a comma or a closing brace."  Just because it isn't *exactly* a comma doesn't change matters: a collection of function arguments *are not* a complete grammar construct.

Secondly, macros cannot parse the output of other macros.  This requires eager expansion, which Rust doesn't have.  [You can only do this using recursion](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-push-down-accumulation.html).